# O(log n) Programming

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, processing-efficiency

I am trying to prepare for a contest but my program speed is always dreadfully slow as I use O(n). First of all, I don't even know how to make it O(log n), or I've never heard about this paradigm. Where can I learn about this?

For example,

If you had an integer array with zeroes and ones, such as [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 ], and now you wanted to replace every 0 with 1 **only if one of it's neighbors** has the value of 1, what is the most efficient way to go about doing if this must occur t number of times? (The program must do this for a number of t times)

EDIT:
Here's my inefficient solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n;
    long t;

    n = input.nextInt();
    t = input.nextLong();
    input.nextLine();

    int[] units = new int[n + 2];
    String inputted = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        units[i] = Integer.parseInt((""+inputted.charAt(i - 1)));
    }

    int[] original;

    for(int j = 0; j <= t -1; j++) {
        units[0] = units[n];
        units[n + 1] = units[1];
        original = units.clone();

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if(((original[i - 1] == 0) && (original[i + 1] == 1)) || ((original[i - 1] == 1) && (original[i + 1] == 0))) {
                units[i] = 1;
            } else {
                units[i] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(units[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't you have to look at every element of the list? How would you be expected to do that in less than `n` steps? Like if all the elements are 0, for example

Comment: O(n) sounds reasonable...........

Comment: @cricket_007 Updated the question.

Comment: @Antoniossss What if I had to sort through it t times?

Comment: @ImagineDragons You think that sorting is less expensive then loop over whole set? Well think again

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't really get all this stuff- I'm just a beginner programmer, I haven't even heard of Ologn till today...

Comment: @Antoniossss I don't really get all this stuff- I'm just a beginner programmer, I haven't even heard of Ologn till today...

Comment: If t < n, that would still be O(n), unless you mean "do the replacement operation repeatedly t times" , then that's O(t*n), so closer to O(n^2) for t >= n

Comment: This get kinda technical, but at least skim through it, skipping parts that are too heavy in math for your taste: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: The problem is on page 10: http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2016/stage%201/seniorEn.pdf

Comment: Maybe you should read over this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation

Comment: The problem says nothing about runtime complexity, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 It's timed, 3 seconds max for a solution. One of mine to 84s...

Comment: I'm guessing `units.clone();` is taking the most time. That'll make your approach more than O(n) because it's ran every time in the loop. Also, converting the string to an int array seems unnecessary

Comment: How do I avoid using units.clone()? @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 Wouldn't I need to convert to string to an int array?

Comment: You can modify the characters of a `StringBuffer` in-place. Don't need any int array. Make `inputted` a `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments, I'm fairly sure you can keep out the array and `clone` operations.

You can modify a `StringBuilder` in-place, so no need to convert back and forth between `int[]` and `String`.

For example, (note: This is on the order of an `O(n)` operation for all `T <= N`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(conway1d("0000001", 7, 1));
    System.out.println(conway1d("01011", 5, 3));
}

private static String conway1d(CharSequence input, int N, long T) {
    System.out.println("Generation 0: " + input);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input); // Will update this for all generations

    StringBuilder copy = new StringBuilder(); // store a copy to reference current generation
    for (int gen = 1; gen <= T; gen++) {
        // Copy over next generation string
        copy.setLength(0);
        copy.append(input);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            conwayUpdate(sb, copy, i, N);
        }

        input = sb.toString(); // next generation string
        System.out.printf("Generation %d: %s\n", gen, input);
    }

    return input.toString();
}

private static void conwayUpdate(StringBuilder nextGen, final StringBuilder currentGen, int charPos, int N) {
    int prev = (N + (charPos - 1)) % N;
    int next = (charPos + 1) % N;

    // **Exactly one** adjacent '1'
    boolean adjacent = currentGen.charAt(prev) == '1' ^ currentGen.charAt(next) == '1';
    nextGen.setCharAt(charPos, adjacent ? '1' : '0'); // set cell as alive or dead
}
```

For the two samples in the problem you posted in the comments, this code generates this output.

```
Generation 0: 0000001
Generation 1: 1000010
1000010
Generation 0: 01011
Generation 1: 00011
Generation 2: 10111
Generation 3: 10100
10100
```

Comment: When the parameters are ("001000000110001", 15, 100000000) it takes 10 seconds, it's not efficient enough. One of the input data is 5449844351151445 generations too... How is it possible to make it more efficient? @cricket_007

Comment: If you remove the `System.out` statements inside `conway1d`, should be slightly faster. This is just the first approach I thought of, but it is certainly faster than your 84s solution

Comment: Well, I don't know C++, but I do know C++ definitely can run faster than Java.

Comment: I would only recommend you learn something that would actually be useful to your interests. For example, I don't know C++ because it isn't necessary for my job.

Answer (score 2):

This is an elementary cellular automaton. Such a dynamical system has properties that you can use for your advantages. In your case, for example, you can set to value 1 every cell at distance at most t from any initial value 1 (cone of light property). Then you may do something like:

- get a 1 in the original sequence, say it is located at position p.
- set to 1 every position from p-t to p+t.

You may then take as your advantage in the next step that you've already set position p-t to p+t... This can let you compute the final step t without computing intermediary steps (good factor of acceleration isn't it?).

You can also use some tricks as HashLife, see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife).

Comment: Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: hard to say it without some finer analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The BigO notation is a simplification to understand the complexity of the Algorithm. Basically, two algorithms O(n) can have very different execution times. Why? Let's unroll your example:

- You have two **nested** loops. The outer loop will run **t** times.
- The inner loop will run **n** times
- For each time the loop executes, it will take a constant **k** time.

So, in essence your algorithm is **O(k * t * n)**. If **t** is in the same order of magnitude of **n**, then you can consider the complexity as **O(k * n^2)**.

There is two approaches to optimize this algorithm:

- Reduce the constant time **k**. For example, do not clone the whole array on each loop, because it is very time consuming (clone needs to do a full array loop to clone).
- The second optimization in this case is to use Dynamic Programing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) that can cache information between two loops and optimize the execution, that can lower **k** or even lower the complexity from O(nˆ2) to O(n * log n).

Comment: How do I not clone the array with my solution? If I don't clone it, it will change the values as it runs...